# unlocaling kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, locale

I have installed kubuntu 13.10

as I am living in israel, every app that I install is immediatly in hebrew which is very annoying.

I always prefer my applications to be in english and just have the ability to write in hebrew.

how do I change it that everything will stay in english?

Answer (score 4):

Try configuring the system for English here:

```
System Settings -> Language Support
```

[This article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) from the Ubuntu Help explains locales in depth.

Answer (score 2):

**Kubuntu / KDE**

The Kubuntu is using KDE System Settings > Locale > Country/Region & Language - Languages tab

[image]

By the KDE Country/Region & Language Help

> Language
>
> In this tab you can set your preferred languages for the KDE Workspace
>   and Applications to be displayed in.
>
> The list of Available Languages shows what KDE translations are
>   available on your system.
>
> The Preferred Languages list shows the languages that will be used
>   when displaying the KDE Workspace and Applications.
>
> You can add a language to the Preferred Languages list by selecting it
>   in the Available Languages and then clicking on the Add arrow button.
>   You can remove a language from the Preferred Languages list by
>   selecting it and then clicking on the Remove arrow button. You can
>   change the order of preference in the Preferred Languages list by
>   selecting a language and clicking on the Up or Down arrow button.

Sometimes the settings are broken - an older topic from the Kubuntu Forums: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62692-LC_*-environment-variables-not-affected-by-quot-System-Settings-quot-gt-quot-Locale-quot